# R maps package - how to draw lines between countries?

Tags: r, maps, latitude-longitude

In R, using maps package, and gcIntermediate  function, how do I draw lines between two countries?  It needs lat-long, but I'm not sure what lat-long should I give for countries (say I want to draw a line between USA and sweden)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple maps you could use, depending on what info/detail/etc. you need, but for this the very nice `wrld_simpl` will do just fine:

```
library(maptools)
library(geosphere)

data(wrld_simpl)

US_lat = wrld_simpl$LAT[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'United States']
US_lon = wrld_simpl$LON[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'United States']

SWE_lat = wrld_simpl$LAT[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'Sweden']
SWE_lon = wrld_simpl$LON[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'Sweden']

points = gcIntermediate(c(US_lon, US_lat), c(SWE_lon, SWE_lat), 100)

dev.new(width=6, height=4)
plot(wrld_simpl)
lines(points, col='red')
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I'm doing it with lines from many countries to Brazil. For some countries after ~120 degrees East (like Australia, New Zealand, Japan...) the lines go east, became strait, go all 360 degrees to the other side of the screen, and then continue its round path. Any way to solve that?